# Mac: Lack of --printf for stat

Tags: macos, unix, stat, bsd

I'm trying to use `stat` on mac (with python), but using this command

```
stat --printf 'name: %n \tSize: %s bytes\t Type: %F\t Timestamp:%z\n' " + j
```

in python gives me a response: `stat: illegal option -- -` which tells me that some of my tags in `stat --printf 'name: %n \tSize: %s bytes\t Type: %F\t Timestamp:%z\n'` are wrong.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `--printf` option does not exist with `stat` on MacOS.

What you're looking for is `-f` (for format).

So you can do:

`stat -f 'name: %n \tSize: %s bytes\t Type: %F\t Timestamp:%z\n'`

Answer (score 1):

Formatting `stat` output on macOS is unlike Linux versions.

```
stat -f 'Name: %N%tType: %HT%tSize: %z%tTimestamp: %SB%n' filename
```

Should return output similar to:

```
Name: filename  Type: Regular File  Size: 27063 Timestamp: Mar 19 01:02:20 2017
```

See also [OS X Man Pages > stat](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html)